# Ansible, loop, register, and stdout

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that looks like this:

```
- hosts: host1
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: "Loop"
    command: "echo {{ item }}"
    with_items: [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
    register: hello
  - debug: "msg={{ hello.results }}"
```

Everything works correctly, and the output is returned, but there is tons and tons of output.  It turns out that this:

```
  - debug: "msg={{ hello.results.1.stdout }}"
```

does exactly what I want -- just grab the stdout from the command -- but only for one of the six times through the loop.

What I really want/need to do is this:

```
  - debug: "msg={{ hello.results.*.stdout }}"
```

where it goes into the `hello` structure, accesses the `results` entry, goes to each member of that array, and pulls out the `stdout` value.

Is this possible?

---

## UPDATE

```
- hosts: host1
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: "Loop"
    command: "echo {{ item }}"
    with_items: [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
    register: hello
  - debug:
      msg: "{{item.stdout}}"
    with_items: "{{hello.results}}"
```

is no less verbose than my original example.

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item={'_ansible_parsed': True, 'stderr_lines': [], u'cmd': [
u'echo', u'0'], u'end': u'2018-01-02 20:53:08.916774', '_ansible_no_log': False
, u'stdout': u'0', '_ansible_item_result': True, u'changed': True, 'item': 0, 
u'delta': u'0:00:00.002137', u'stderr': u'', u'rc': 0, u'invocation': {u'module_
args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': False, u'_raw_params
': u'echo 0', u'removes': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None, u'stdin': Non
e}}, 'stdout_lines': [u'0'], u'start': u'2018-01-02 20:53:08.914637', 'failed':
 False}) => {
    "item": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": [
            "echo",
            "0"
        ],
        "delta": "0:00:00.002137",
        "end": "2018-01-02 20:53:08.916774",
        "failed": false,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "_raw_params": "echo 0",
                "_uses_shell": false,
                "chdir": null,
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "removes": null,
                "stdin": null,
                "warn": true
            }
        },
        "item": 0,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2018-01-02 20:53:08.914637",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "0",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "0"
        ]
    },
    "msg": "0"
}
```

I get 6 copies of the above construct.

It feels like I'm close but I'm still doing something wrong.  I see `"msg": "0"` at the bottom, which is what I want.  I just don't want the rest of it.

Comment: Something similar confused me: In your UPDATE section, most of the output is the 'label' for each item in the loop. With Ansible now preferring `loop` I've put a possible workaround as an answer below with `loop_control`.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**:

```
- debug: "msg={{ hello.results | map(attribute='stdout') | join('\n') }}"
```

---

**Remark**:

By default, Ansible will print visible `\n` two-character sequences instead of wrapping the lines, so either use a callback plugin for a human readable output ([example](https://github.com/n0ts/ansible-human_log)) or verify the method with:

```
- copy:
    content: "{{ hello.results | map(attribute='stdout') | join('\n') }}"
    dest: ./result.txt
```

and check the contents of the `result.txt`.

Comment: `TASK [debug] fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'map'. String: {{ hello.results | map(attribute='stdout') | join('\n') }}"}`    perhaps i am missing a library or an add-in or something... or perhaps my version of ansible is too old.

Comment: Fix your Ansible/Jinja2 installation. `map` was added in Jinja2 2.7 (in [May 2013](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Jinja2/2.7)!), so your installation is either ancient, or broken.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the keyword **loop** to get **stdout** from all iterations of the previous loop:

```
loop: "{{ hello | json_query('results[*].stdout') }}"
```

I find json_query easiest to use in such register-loop situations. Official documentation can be found here ==> [json-query-filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  The ansible website has documentation that explains [how to use `register` in a loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop).  You just need to iterate over the `hello.results` array, as in:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{item.stdout}}"
  with_items: "{{hello.results}}"
```

Comment: If you look at the `msg` key in the results, you will see that it is correctly iterating over the list of results.  If you want less verbose output, do something other than using a `debug` task.

Comment: I'm very new to ansible.  Can you give me some other options?  `debug` was the only thing I could find that generated the command's stdout.

Comment: What do you want to *do* with the output? Ansible isn't really a tool fir displaying things.   It's a tool for *doing* things. Do you want to write the output to a file? Send it to another command? Etc.

Comment: I just want to log the command output, either to a file or (ideally) to a session that i can capture with `script`.  If the tool is going to do important things, I'd need a verbose log of what it did and what the results of the commands were, for future troubleshooting/recordkeeping.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
- debug: "msg={{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items: "{{ hello.results }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this construct works well enough for my needs.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    stuff: [ 0,2,4,6,8,10 ]
  tasks:
  - name: "Loop"
    command: "echo {{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ stuff }}"
    register: hello
  - debug: "var=hello.results.{{item}}.stdout"
    with_sequence: "0-{{stuff|length - 1}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at a similar problem and was confused by getting lots of output when I was expecting a relatively small `msg` or `var` from `debug:`. Turns out most of that output was the 'label' with which Ansible was prefixing each of those small outputs. It being a few years after this question was originally asked I've been using `loop` rather than `with_items`; this also has a `label:` option in `loop_control:`, so in my case for a similar problem - getting any `/etc/passwd` entries for users 'alice' or 'bob',

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 1  # output easier to read when grouped by host
  tasks:
    - name: Look for users in /etc/passwd
      command: grep {{ item }} /etc/passwd
      register: res
      ignore_errors: true
      loop:
       - alice
       - bob
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.stdout_lines }}"
      when: not item.failed
      loop: "{{ res.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
```