# Ansible: Output of 'loop' with 'register' module

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm trying to get the output of my Ansible script using `register` module but the `loop` I'm using is probably causing some issue.

Whats a default way of using `register` module with `loop`?

Code:

```yaml
---
  - name:
    hosts:
    gather_facts:

    tasks:
        - name: Execute file
          ansible.builtin.shell: 
          environment:
                   "setting environment"
          register: output
          loop:
             "value"

         - debug:
              vars: output.std_lines
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Whats a default way of using `register` module with `loop`?*

It is just registering the result.

The only difference will be, that a single task will provide you just with an dictionary `result` (or `output` in your example) and registering in a loop will provide with a list `result.results` (or `output.results` in your example). To access the `.stdout_lines` you will need to loop over the result set `.results` too.

You may have a look into the following example playbook which will show some aspects of [Registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables), [Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html), data structures, dicts and lists and type debugging.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Create STDOUT output (single)
    command: 'echo "1"'
    register: result

  - name: Show full result (single)
    debug:
      var: result

  - name: Show '.stdout' (single)
    debug:
      msg: "The result in '.stdout': {{ result.stdout }} is of type {{ result.stdout | type_debug }}"

  - name: Create STDOUT output (loop)
    command: 'echo "{{ item }}"'
    register: result
    loop: [1, 2, 3]
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item }}"

  - name: Show full result (loop)
    debug:
      var: result

  - name: Show '.stdout' (loop)
    debug:
      msg: "The result in '.stdout': {{ item.stdout }} is of type {{ item.stdout | type_debug }}"
    loop: "{{ result.results }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

By running it and going through the output you can get familiar with the differences  in your tasks.

**Further Q&A**

- [Register Variables in Loop in an Ansible Playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29636407/6771046)
- [Ansible: `loop`, `register`, and `stdout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067059/)
- [Register variables in `loop` in Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29564339/6771046)

... and many more here on SO.